# jQuery - Read more - Multiple paragraphs with character limit

Tags: jquery

Below you will find my JSFiddle. I have a limit of 500 chars on the first paragraph and this is how the "More" link is added and then after the "More" link I just hide the rest of the content of that paragraph and all following paragraphs.

My issue is with the last set of paragraphs. I have a paragraph at the beginning of the set that is under 500 chars so it does not take the rules into account. How can I keep the paragraph by paragraph layout but have the char count account for the text in multiple paragraphs.

I am happy to provide more details just ask. Thanks in advance.

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/h36s3d1u/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="readMoreContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan. Nunc dapibus ante non leo dapibus rhoncus. Nunc nunc lorem, tristique a sodales a, ultricies vitae ipsum. Nam finibus lorem nec est fermentum, vitae suscipit lacus aliquam. Vivamus egestas laoreet justo, non pulvinar quam tristique vitae. Vestibulum gravida risus purus, ac egestas mi vestibulum vitae. Quisque sagittis convallis lorem, vel iaculis eros placerat vitae. Etiam ultricies metus justo. Donec in diam metus. In eu nisi et velit luctus vehicula vitae in nisi. Vivamus tempor interdum dignissim. Vivamus viverra odio quis mauris mollis aliquam. Integer eu rutrum lectus, ut tempus erat. Phasellus ut lectus vitae elit luctus laoreet vel sit amet lorem. Maecenas consequat nunc vel libero feugiat, sed tristique sapien imperdiet. Fusce quis lobortis justo, eget ultricies eros. Integer feugiat tortor a enim vulputate eleifend. Proin malesuada metus venenatis se.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan. Nunc dapibus ante non leo dapibus rhoncus. Nunc nunc lorem, tristique a sodales a, ultricies vitae ipsum. Nam finibus lorem nec est fermentum, vitae suscipit lacus aliquam. Vivamus egestas laoreet justo, non pulvinar quam tristique vitae. Vestibulum gravida risus purus, ac egestas mi vestibulum vitae. Quisque sagittis convallis lorem, vel iaculis eros placerat vitae. Etiam ultricies metus justo. Donec in diam metus. In eu nisi et velit luctus vehicula vitae in nisi. Vivamus tempor interdum dignissim. Vivamus viverra odio quis mauris mollis aliquam. Integer eu rutrum lectus, ut tempus erat. Phasellus ut lectus vitae elit luctus laoreet vel sit amet lorem. Maecenas consequat nunc vel libero feugiat, sed tristique sapien imperdiet. Fusce quis lobortis justo, eget ultricies eros. Integer feugiat tortor a enim vulputate eleifend. Proin malesuada metus venenatis se.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan. Nunc dapibus ante non leo dapibus rhoncus. Nunc nunc lorem, tristique a sodales a, ultricies vitae ipsum. Nam finibus lorem nec est fermentum, vitae suscipit lacus aliquam. Vivamus egestas laoreet justo, non pulvinar quam tristique vitae. Vestibulum gravida risus purus, ac egestas mi vestibulum vitae. Quisque sagittis convallis lorem, vel iaculis eros placerat vitae. Etiam ultricies metus justo. Donec in diam metus. In eu nisi et velit luctus vehicula vitae in nisi. Vivamus tempor interdum dignissim. Vivamus viverra odio quis mauris mollis aliquam. Integer eu rutrum lectus, ut tempus erat. Phasellus ut lectus vitae elit luctus laoreet vel sit amet lorem. Maecenas consequat nunc vel libero feugiat, sed tristique sapien imperdiet. Fusce quis lobortis justo, eget ultricies eros. Integer feugiat tortor a enim vulputate eleifend. Proin malesuada metus venenatis se.</p></div>

<div class="readMoreContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan. Nunc dapibus ante non leo dapibus rhoncus. Nunc nunc lorem, tristique a sodales a, ultricies vitae ipsum. Nam finibus lorem nec est fermentum, vitae suscipit lacus aliquam. Vivamus egestas laoreet justo, non pulvinar quam tristique vitae. Vestibulum gravida risus purus, ac egestas mi vestibulum vitae. Quisque sagittis convallis lorem, vel iaculis eros placerat vitae. Etiam ultricies metus justo. Donec in diam metus. In eu nisi et velit luctus vehicula vitae in nisi. Vivamus tempor interdum dignissim. Vivamus viverra odio quis mauris mollis aliquam. Integer eu rutrum lectus, ut tempus erat. Phasellus ut lectus vitae elit luctus laoreet vel sit amet lorem. Maecenas consequat nunc vel libero feugiat, sed tristique sapien imperdiet. Fusce quis lobortis justo, eget ultricies eros. Integer feugiat tortor a enim vulputate eleifend. Proin malesuada metus venenatis se.</p></div>

<div class="readMoreContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque et magna velit. Sed quis enim non risus dapibus accumsan. Nunc dapibus ante non leo dapibus rhoncus. Nunc nunc lorem, tristique a sodales a, ultricies vitae ipsum. Nam finibus lorem nec est fermentum, vitae suscipit lacus aliquam. Vivamus egestas laoreet justo, non pulvinar quam tristique vitae. Vestibulum gravida risus purus, ac egestas mi vestibulum vitae. Quisque sagittis convallis lorem, vel iaculis eros placerat vitae. Etiam ultricies metus justo. Donec in diam metus. In eu nisi et velit luctus vehicula vitae in nisi. Vivamus tempor interdum dignissim. Vivamus viverra odio quis mauris mollis aliquam. Integer eu rutrum lectus, ut tempus erat. Phasellus ut lectus vitae elit luctus laoreet vel sit amet lorem. Maecenas consequat nunc vel libero feugiat, sed tristique sapien imperdiet. Fusce quis lobortis justo, eget ultricies eros. Integer feugiat tortor a enim vulputate eleifend. Proin malesuada metus venenatis se.</p></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".readMoreContent").each(function() {

    var paragraphs = $(this).find('p');
    var counter = 1;
    var ellipses = '<span class="ellipses"> ... </span>';
    var more = ' <a href="#" class="more">More</a>';
    var less = ' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a>';

    paragraphs.each(function(){  

        if(counter==1){

            $(this).addClass("first");

            var t = $(this).text();

            if(t.length < 500) return;
                $(this).html(t.slice(0,500)+ellipses+more+'<span class="hiddenPart">'+t.slice(500,t.length)+'</span>');
                $(this).parent().children().last().append(less);
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
        }

        counter++;

    });

    $('.hiddenPart').hide();

    $('.less').hide();

    $('.more').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).parent().nextAll().show();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.less').show();
    });

    $('a.less').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.ellipses,.more').show();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.first').find('.hiddenPart').hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('p').not('.first').hide();
    });

});
```

**Alternate solution idea:**

I could get all the ".html" instead of ".text" but then I need to somehow tell the char count to not include the "p" tags and then spit the html back out with the "p" tags in the correct place. This is the only solution I could think of but I do not even know where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood, but does swapping `var paragraphs = $(this).find('p');` for `var paragraphs = $(this);` solve your problem?

Comment: @Ryan Gee - Sadly no. The paragraph structure will no longer exist id we do this.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what is supposed to happen - is the first (smaller) paragraph supposed to be included in the next paragraph's "read more" block, but remain as an independent paragraph?

Comment: @Ryan Gee - Yes the paragraph needs to be included in the count but remain independent.